# AppCompat Classes Not Found in Eclipse

Tags: android, android-support-library

OK, maybe it's just the lack of sleep, but I am having difficulty getting AppCompat classes to be visible in [my Eclipse project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ActionBar/AppCompat), despite the fact that:

- this project used to work
- a Gradle build of this project works fine

Here's my Eclipse project setup:

[image: ActionBarCompatDemo project setup in Eclipse]

So, I have:

- `android-support-v4.jar` in `libs/`
- `android-support-v7-appcompat` attached as an Android library project

The symptom is that the AppCompat classes are not visible: Eclipse reports "The import android.support.v7.app cannot be resolved" when I try to import `android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity`. The `android-support-v7-appcompat.jar` file appears to have the class, and it appears to be properly added to my build path (by virtue of being in "Android Dependencies", which is checked in the Eclipse build path dialog).

Other notes:

- I temporarily removed the appcompat library project from the Eclipse configuration, exported Gradle build files, and added it back, with no effect on Eclipse. Adding `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.0.1'` to the `dependencies` block in the Gradle build file was sufficient to get the project to build using **`gradle assembleDebug`**, so it's not like I have the import statement wrong.
- I created a new project and have the same issue there, so it is not tied to this specific project.
- The SDK Manager reports that I have 19.0.1 of the Android Support Library installed.
- I have cleaned this project and `appcompat`, restarted Eclipse, and have tried various profanities, with no effect on Eclipse.

Any suggestions as to where I am going wrong?

**UPDATE**

Here's my Java build path, per Eclipse:

[image: Eclipse Java build path]

Comment: does it show as Android Dependencias on the Java Build Path screen, libraries tab?

Comment: @ferdy182: If by "it" you mean `android-support-v7-appcompat.jar`, then yes it does. I have added a screenshot of that tab to the question. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to right lick on the project, then Android Tools, pa Add support library?

Comment: I had lots of strange issues when I tried to be clever and do a soft link (in windows) from my workspace to a different drive for the android-support-v7-appcompat library project in the SDK extras dir.  Not sure if there are any similar oddities on Linux.  Doesn't seem related to what you were doing, but I had similar errors in my app that used the library project.  I ended up copying the project over, as well as doing the 'build path'->'add to build path' for the libs, which I hadn't needed to do that way for library projects or lib jars before.

Comment: @Zookey: That has never worked on my development machine, due to some peculiarities with my setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I'm not completely certain what I did, but it's now working.

The most likely situation is that the directory had some of the wrong files marked read-only. Allowing all files to be writeable, plus restarting Eclipse for the fourth time today, eliminated my problems, in both projects (the one depicted above and another one).

Now, it's entirely possible that I did something else along the way that got picked up by the restart of Eclipse, or just that Eclipse wanted to restart (again) before it decided to behave.

Anyway, thanks to all who provided advice!

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked if the android-support-v4.jar is the same version in both projects? When you are using appcompat, in fact, you don't need the android-support-v4.jar, as it is packed in appcompat project. Another try is to verify if the Project Build Target of appcompat is <= project build target of your project.

Comment: I had tried it both with and without a local copy of `android-support-v4.jar`, with no effect. The build target of `appcompat` was lower than the build target of the project. Thanks, though!

Answer (score 1):

Remove support jar from your project, since support jar is there in app-compat lib also.

Comment: This was already mentioned in another answer, and it did not have an effect.

Comment: For me it worked, but you need to restart the eclipse after removing the support jar.